# Scraping site when links point to javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrape the PDF linked for each location here. If you go to 'show media' you can see the locations, then clicking the thumbnail downloads the PDFs.

I'd like to scrape all the PDFs, but can't figure out how to access the PDFs in a script because they appear to point to javascript:void(0).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

http://www.outfrontmedia.com/whereweare/pages/mediafinder.aspx